# Office 365 api draft flag

Tags: office365api

I have an Office 365 extension that provides its own "Send" button which does some custom processing of the "draft" email and sends it through other means (ie not Office 365 Web). Since the email isn't sent by Outlook it never makes it to the sent folder (which makes sense). I would like to take that draft email and move it to the sent folder and remove the draft flag so it looks like it was sent by Outlook 365 Web.

```
        var getMessageUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + itemId;
        var data = JSON.stringify({ 'ToRecipients': [{ 'EmailAddress': { 'Address': 'sheprts@cox.net', 'Name': 'Katie Jordan' } }], 'IsRead': true, 'IsDraft': false });
        $.ajax({
            url: getMessageUrl,
            type: 'PATCH',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: data
        })
            })
            .done(function (item) {
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                var err = ""
            });
```

The request above works fine except the changing of the draft flag. If this isn't the solution what else can I do? I need to get a draft email into the sent folder as "Not" a draft.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot create non-draft messages using the API.

Answer (score 0):

Change your "other means" and set the "SaveInSentFolder" flag; or change to SMTP for your "other means".